# Proper way to use AsyncStorage in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-state, asyncstorage

I want to create a simple app that tracks reading progress for chapters. On a chapter page I display the info about the chapter and I provide a slider to update the progress. The problem is that I do not understand how to save correctly to the Async Storage. Right now, the version that seems to work seems messy.

This is how I interact with the storage:

```
export default function useDataManagement() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const [chapters, setChapters] =
    useState<AllChaptersSignature>(initialChapters);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadChapters().then((loadedChapters: any) => {
      setChapters(loadedChapters);
    });
  }, [isFocused]);

  const loadChapters = async () => {
    try {
      const storageData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('chapters');
      if (storageData) {
        let obj: AllChaptersSignature = JSON.parse(storageData);
        return obj;
      }
      return initialChapters;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error loading chapters: ', error);
      return initialChapters;
    }
  };

  const saveChapters = async (newChapters: any) => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.setItem(
        'chapters',
        JSON.stringify(newChapters),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error saving Chapters: ', error);
    }
  };

  return {
    chapters,
    saveChapters,
  };
}
```

And in the view component of the Chapter I use:

```
const {chapters, saveChapters} = useDataManagement();
```

But in order for everything to stay up-to-date on change I duplicated the fields of a chapter in another variable

```
 const [displayCurrentPage, setDisplayCurrentPage] = useState(
    chapters[currentChapterId].currentPage,
  );
```

This seems to work fine when updating the currentPage with the slider. The problem is that I want to have a `timesRecapped` field in a chapter and so when the slider is pulled all the way the chapter is put to done and timesRecapped is increased. Then the user can press a reset button that should reset everything to the beggining, but keep the timesRecapped field as is.

```
  function resetDisplayedChapter() {
    var tempChapter = prepareUpdateChapter(
      chapters[currentChapterId],
      'isDone',
      false,
    );
    setIsDone(false);
    setDisplayCurrentPage(chapters[currentChapterId].startPage);
    tempChapter = prepareUpdateChapter(
      tempChapter,
      'currentPage',
      tempChapter.startPage,
    );
    var changedChapters: any = [tempChapter];
    if (isParent) {
      changedChapters.push(
        chapters[currentChapterId].childChapters
          .map((index: any) => chapters[Number(index)])
          .map((childChapter: any) => resetSubChapter(childChapter)),
      );
    }
    changedChapters = changedChapters.flat();
    var tempChapters = {...chapters};
    changedChapters.forEach((changedChapter: any) => {
      tempChapters[Number(changedChapter.id)] = changedChapter;
    });
    updateReadProgress(tempChapter, tempChapters);
    saveChapters(tempChapters);
  }
```

I know that multiple changes to the same state in a function does not work and that's why I use

```
  function prepareUpdateChapter(
    tempChapter: ChapterSignature,
    key: any,
    newValue: any,
  ) {
    return {...tempChapter, [key]: newValue};
  }
```

And only at the very end I call the saveChapters method. This works, but only once. I have to press the back button and come back if I want the reset to work as expected. If I keep using the slider and the reset button without going back, the timesRecapped field does not keep increasing. I think it's because the chapters that is being used in the resetDisplayedChapter are not changing, but I do not know how to handle this.

Here is how I increase timesRecapped also:

```
  function handleIfDone(tempChapter: ChapterSignature): ChapterSignature {
    if (
      tempChapter.currentPage >= chapters[currentChapterId].endPage &&
      // !chapters[currentChapterId].isDone &&
      chapters[currentChapterId].childChapters.length == 0
    ) {
      var otherTempChapter = prepareUpdateChapter(
        tempChapter,
        'timesRecapped',
        tempChapter.timesRecapped + 1,
      );
      otherTempChapter = prepareUpdateChapter(otherTempChapter, 'isDone', true);
      return otherTempChapter;
    } else {
      return tempChapter;
    }
  }
```

Which is used here:

```
const handleSliderComplete = (value: number) => {
    var tempChapter = prepareUpdateChapter(
      chapters[currentChapterId],
      'currentPage',
      value,
    );
    updateReadProgress(tempChapter, chapters);
    tempChapter = handleIfDone(tempChapter);
    setCurrentChapter(tempChapter);
    saveChapters(prepareUpdateAllChapters(tempChapter));
  };
```

Anyway, what I am looking for, besides fixing this bug, is how to write this more cleanly.